# openethereum - high gase, transactions get culled / too many trasnaction in queue

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, openethereum

We have the following `openethereum` service (docker-compose)

```
version: '2.3' 
services:
    ethereum:
      # using v2.6.2-beta as it's stable
      # paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/10371
      image: openethereum/openethereum:v3.2.3
      user: openethereum
      ports:
        - "****:****"
        - "****:****"
      volumes:
        - /mnt/storage/ethereum:/home/openethereum/.local/share/openethereum/
      # --warp is set by default
      command: 
        --config /home/openethereum/.local/share/openethereum/config.toml
        --no-persistent-txqueue
        --tx-queue-per-sender 5000       
      restart: always
```

With the following `config.toml`:

```
[parity]
mode_timeout = 500
base_path = "/home/openethereum/.local/share/openethereum/"
db_path = "/home/openethereum/.local/share/openethereum/chains"
keys_path = "/home/openethereum/.local/share/openethereum/keys"

[network]
port = ****

[rpc]
port = ****
interface = "all"
apis = ["all"]
#apis = ["web3", "eth", "pubsub", "net", "parity", "rpc"]
hosts = ["all"]

[footprint]
# If defined will never use more then 6144MB for all caches. (Overrides other cache settings).
cache_size = 6144
```

Now, we publish anywhere between 10 to a 200 txs an hour. whenever too many txs are coming out either one of 2 things happens:

1. Transactions are getting culled
2. Transactions get rejected / fail to publish with 'too many transaction in queue' error

How can we solve this?

Side note: we always try to pay 25-50 gWei more than the 'Trader' fee recommendation on etherscan GasTracker